# Why does my EV3 not have data logging in Brick App menu?

Tags: ev3

I recently purchased a 45544 Educator Mindstorms product. In working through tutorials.  I am at section on data logging, but my Brick Apps menu stops at Brick Program. Data Logging is not on menu

My Brick Info is VO 60, FW V1.07H

Answer (score 2):

The brick currently has the "Home" version of the firmware loaded as indicated by the "H" in 1.07H. You can use the Education version of the desktop EV3 programming software to load the educational version of the firmware (ends in "E"). Data logging is only present in the educational version.

Comment: That solved the problem.  Would be nice if they shipped with the E version of firmware in their E product, but at least the firmware update allowed me to switch versions. Whew.  Thx