# Why do I not have the Brick Datalog app in the LEGO Mindstorms EV3 V1.10E firmware?

Tags: ev3

> I realize a similar question has been asked (you can view it [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9241/why-does-my-ev3-not-have-data-logging-in-brick-app-menu)) however mine is slightly different.

I have a Lego Mindstorms EV3 Home Set 31313 and due to recommendation, I installed Lego Mindstorms Education EV3 Student Edition. I later changed my firmware on my EV3 to V1.09E. The next time I updated my firmware, however, I was unsure that the software was not installing the latest version so I ended up installing V1.10E using EV3 Manager. So it was to my surprise that the Brick Datalog app had disappeared!

Is there any way for me to get my app back without, of course, performing a downgrade and removing the ability for me to use Microsoft PXT?
TIA!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting insight. I didn't notice that it was missing. (I wonder if there was not enough room in the flash memory for both this and the new MakeCode stuff - or maybe it was just an accident).

I managed to find a hack to get the `Brick Datalog` program loaded again.

1. Download [this](http://files.lechnology.com/lego/mindstorms/ev3/Brick%20Datalog.zip) zip file.
2. Unzip the file.
3. Open `Brick Datalog.ev3` in the EV3 programming software.
4. Download the project to your EV3.
5. Open the *Memory Browser*.

   [image: Screenshot with arrow pointing to Open Memory Browser icon]
6. Browse to the `Brick Datalog` project, then click *Download*.

   [image: Screenshot of the Memory Browser with arrows pointing to the Brick Datalog folder and the Download button]
7. Select the `Brick Datalog.rbf` file (from where you unziped the file in step 2) and click *Open*.

   [image: Screenshot of the file Open dialog with Brick Datalog.rbf selected and an arrows pointing to the Brick Datalog.rbf file and the Open button]
8. Close the *Memory Browser*.
9. On the EV3 brick, you can now browse to the `Brick Datalog` project and run the `Brick Datalog` program (it won't be with the rest of the "apps" as in previous versions of the firmware).

How it works:

The brick apps use the same format as user-created programs on the EV3, so I just took the `Brick Datalog` app from the [ev3dev lms2012-compat](https://github.com/ev3dev/lms2012-compat) project (which is identical to the official LEGO version, but easier to get to). Then I created a new empty project in the EV3 Education software and imported all of the images and sounds. The software doesn't let you import `.rbf` files (the actual program), which is why it has to be downloaded separately via the *Memory Browser*.

I haven't tested this extensively, but it does seem to work.

Comment: It's certainly not an issue with storage or memory limitations. EV3s doesn't really suffer from those like the RCXs or NXTs do. Excellent workaround though!

Comment: Thank you very much for finally warning me that my EV3 lacked this app for so many years! What I mean is, My EV3 NEVER had the Brick Datalog app on it. Right when I pulled it out out of its amazon box, I immediately explored the features of the brick and I recall knowing that there was no such app. Especially before I updated to the latest firmware, it still was never there.

Comment: Erm... the Brick Datalog project simply does not exist! I can't find it, so I can't follow the instructions above.

Comment: Step 1 provides a link to download the required files.