# How do I erase all old programs using the new scratch type Education software?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, software

I have 24 Lego Mindstorms EV3 bricks that have old programs and the bricks are named. I want to erase them so they can be used for new students. In the older Mindstorms software I would just reinstall the firmware from the tools menu. That would easily clear off the bricks. How do I do that with the new scratch type Mindstorms Education software? I don't see that command.

Comment: Are you using the EV3 Microsoft Makecode site? The website is incapable of interacting with a real EV3, that's why it makes differently-formatted programs and uses a *simulation* of the EV3.

Comment: I am using the new Lego Mindstorms EV3 Education software for PC downloaded from the Lego website. It does not seem to have any way to erase all old programs and to reset settings the previous students may have changed..

Answer (score 4):

The [LEGO Education Website EV3 firmware update page](https://education.lego.com/en-us/support/mindstorms-ev3/firmware-update) lists two options.

1. Use the [EV3 Device Manager](https://ev3manager.education.lego.com/) web page. The instructions are not entirely clear, but if you visit the web page with Chrome (recommended), Safari, Edge, or Internet Explorer, click the *Available Bricks (0)* button and wait a very long time, it will eventually pop up a dialog asking to download and install an *EV3 Device Manager* program to your computer. The EV3 Connection Manager program runs in the background on your computer and communicates with the EV3 Connection Manager web page in the browser. After installing the separate background program, the web page will be able to connect to your EV3. Then you can use it to update the firmware. It does not appear that this method gives you the option of selecting which firmware file to use. It will likely give you v1.10E, which has some known issues (EV3 acts as USB mass storage device which doesn't always work, and [on-brick data log app is missing](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/10347/3498)). But that version should work fine for most uses.
2. If you have Windows, Chromebook or older macOS (10.14 Mojave or earlier), you can also install the older software and use that. It is available from the LEGO Education [retired products download page](https://education.lego.com/en-us/downloads/retiredproducts). (Android and iOS versions might not work due to lack of USB connectivity needed for firmware update.)

Comment: I do have an old Macbook  at home that can probably run the older Lego software. Now that I see it is still available I can use that to clean up the bricks, thank you! Too bad the new software does not have this feature, oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Just do a hard reset on your brick.  Each student can do that

Comment: Good answer, but perhaps expand by explaining how one does that?

Answer (score 0):

I looked up hard reset. Plug into USB, hold down back, center and right buttons. When it shuts off release the back button, then the rest. The brick will reset. Thank you so much, you saved me so much time!!